# javascript game sprite positioning

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-js

I'm trying to create a chess board, and place it in the middle of the screen, so far i cannot get it to be directly in the center. i don't want to hard code the position to the screen because i'm going to be dealing with different screen sizes.

```
    var winsize = cc.director.getWinSize();
    var centerpos = cc.p(winsize.width / 2, winsize.height / 2);

    for (i=0; i<64; i++){
        var tile = cc.Sprite.create(res.tile_png);
        this.addChild(tile,0);
        tile.setPosition(winsize.width+i%8*50/-10, winsize.height-Math.floor(i/8)*50);

    }
```

But the tiles and positioning is completely off

Answer (score 1):

@jumpman8947, if you're using Cocos2d js perhaps you have a similar line: `cc.view.setDesignResolutionSize(480, 320, cc.ResolutionPolicy.SHOW_ALL);`

In this particular case the game will scale to any sceeen, but still run in 480x320 resolution, so no matter what screen resoultion you use, the center in the cocos world would always be `cc.p(240, 160)` so no matter what's the window size or the screen resolution, the resolution of the game stays the same

You can read more about resolution policies here (and in official js-doc): 
http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Multiple_Resolution_Policy_for_Cocos2d-JS
Also please be aware, that the Sprite position in Cocos is the position of the **centre of the sprite**, not bottom left corner

Answer (score 0):

In your question it's not completely clear exactly what you want. However, I made some assumptions. The explanation for my solution is embedded in the comments in the code below.

```js
// var winsize = cc.director.getWinSize();
// Here is some example hard-coded return values:
var winsize = {width: 600, height: 400};
// You can change these numbers to see how they influence
// the outcome.

// var centerpos = cc.p(winsize.width / 2, winsize.height / 2);
// This line doesn't seem relevant for the question you asked.
// Or, rather, the following calculations will result in the tiles
// being centred on the screen anyway, so this calculation here
// is unnecessary.

// Being a chess board, I assume that you want the tiles to be square,
// i.e. to have the same width and height.
// If so, first find out which is the minimum dimension
// and calculate the tile size as being 1/8 of that.
var minDimn = Math.min(winsize.width, winsize.height);
var tileSize = minDimn / 8;

// Find out how far in from the left and how far down from the top
// you need the upper left corner of the upper left tile to start.
// This assumes that you don't need any "margin" around the board.
// (If you do need such a "margin", basically subtract it twice
// from each of winsize.width and winsize.height above.)
// Start with default values of 0 for each, but then add in the
// excess for the longer dimension, but divide it by two
// because that excess will be split between either
// the top and bottom or the left and right.
var xStart = 0, yStart = 0;
if (winsize.width > winsize.height) {
  xStart = (winsize.width - winsize.height) / 2;
} else if (winsize.height > winsize.width) {
  yStart = (winsize.height - winsize.width) / 2;
}

// Instead of looping through all 64 positions in one loop,
// loop through all the horizontal positions in an outer loop
// and all the vertical positions in an inner loop.
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  // For the horizontal dimension, calculate x for each tile
  // as the starting position of the left-most tile plus
  // the width of the tile multiplied by the number of tiles (0-based)
  var x = xStart + i * tileSize;
  // Now the inner loop
  for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
    // Same type of calculation for the y value.
    var y = yStart + j * tileSize;
    // You can see the values in this demo here.
    document.write("<pre>(" + x + ", " + y + ")</pre>");

    // The following two lines don't seem to be relevant to the question.
    // var tile = cc.Sprite.create(res.tile_png);
    // this.addChild(tile,0);
    
    // Use your calculated values in your function call.
    // tile.setPosition(x, y);
  }
}
```